# Convert to string array in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like

```
a = ["PG,PGR"]
```

how to convert this to

```
["PG","PGR"]
```

Comment: Can you add your complete code of how you're getting this array?

Comment: [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: if that's how u r getting the string. write it the way u desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.split(',')` function. It splits a string into an array of substrings that were separated by `','` character, and return a new array.For more info about split function please visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) link.

```
 var a = ["PG,PGR"]
     a= a[0].split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : iterate array and use `split(",")` which will return you new array.

```js
var a = ["PG,PGR"];
var newArray = new Array();
$.each(a , function(i,v){
   newArray.push(v.split(",")); 
});
alert(newArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the below fiddle

```
var array = ["PG,PGR"]
alert(array[0].split(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kishore_Indraganti/fbrkx90n/

Answer (score 0):

The following can handle arrays like `["PG,PGR","a","asd,asdsa"]` also.

```js
function load(){
    var a = ["PG,PGR","a","asd,asdsa"];
    document.getElementById('test').value = a.join(',').split(',');
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="" type="text">
<input value="Load" type="button" onclick="load()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newArray = new Array(["PG,PGR"]);

$.each(newArray, function( index, value ) {
  alert( value + ",");
});
```